# Set Order Of Imported Product Images Using CSV Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, csv, importexport

**Does anyone know if there is a way to set the order of the images being imported in the additional_images column when running a CSV import?**

It's worth noting that 3 of the 5 product images already exist in the system. When running some tests it seems that Magento 2 doesn't import the images in the order that they appear in the  CSV file. See below:

```
additional_images

"/k/l/klb159.jpg,/k/l/klb159-a.jpg,/k/l/klb159-b.jpg,KLB159-C.jpg,KLB159-D.jpg"
```

Images C and D currently do not exist in the system.

After running a successful import the images appear in the following order:

1. PROD1-C.jpg
2. PROD1.jpg
3. PROD1-D.jpg
4. PROD1-A.jpg
5. PROD1-B.jpg

Answer (score -1):

you can [change images order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282818/set-order-of-imported-product-images-using-csv-magento-2-2) with the third-party tool, having even only 3 columns in the file (if it's and update) -  product ID, column with images and column with images position.